# How to find value in table and push button in row under?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to find value in table and later push button which is connected with this value. Here is my example, I have compare products, and I want to remove from compare product/products which are "Out of Stock".

Here is page I'm working [enter link description here](http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/compare)

Here is my code:

```
public void findAvailability(){

    String searchingAvailabilityValue = "Out Of Stock";
    int availabilityPosition =0;
    int numOfFields =   availabilityFields.size();

    for(int i=0;i<numOfFields;i++){
        String availabilityValues = availabilityFields.get(i).getText();

        if(availabilityValues.contains(searchingAvailabilityValue)){
            availabilityPosition = i+2;
            WebElement removeButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table/tbody[2]/tr/td["+availabilityPosition+"]/a"));
            removeButton.click();                           
        }   

    }
```

It work but not at all, i have error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementListHandler.invoke(LocatingElementListHandler.java:39)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.get(Unknown Source)
    at pages.HomePage.findAvailability(HomePage.java:96)
```

Here is html:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Product
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=48">
        <strong>iPod Classic
        </strong>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=36">
        <strong>iPod Nano
        </strong>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=34">
        <strong>iPod Shuffle
        </strong>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="http://demo.opencart.com/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=32">
        <strong>iPod Touch
        </strong>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Image
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">              
      <img src="http://demo.opencart.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/ipod_classic_1-90x90.jpg" alt="iPod Classic" title="iPod Classic" class="img-thumbnail">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">              
      <img src="http://demo.opencart.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/ipod_nano_1-90x90.jpg" alt="iPod Nano" title="iPod Nano" class="img-thumbnail">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">              
      <img src="http://demo.opencart.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/ipod_shuffle_1-90x90.jpg" alt="iPod Shuffle" title="iPod Shuffle" class="img-thumbnail">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">              
      <img src="http://demo.opencart.com/image/cache/catalog/demo/ipod_touch_1-90x90.jpg" alt="iPod Touch" title="iPod Touch" class="img-thumbnail">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Price
    </td>
    <td>                            $122.00                            
    </td>
    <td>                            $122.00                            
    </td>
    <td>                            $122.00                            
    </td>
    <td>                            $122.00                            
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Model
    </td>
    <td>product 20
    </td>
    <td>Product 9
    </td>
    <td>Product 7
    </td>
    <td>Product 5
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Brand
    </td>
    <td>Apple
    </td>
    <td>Apple
    </td>
    <td>Apple
    </td>
    <td>Apple
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Availability
    </td>
    <td>Out Of Stock
    </td>
    <td>2-3 Days
    </td>
    <td>2-3 Days
    </td>
    <td>2-3 Days
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rating
    </td>
    <td class="rating">                            
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <br>
      Based on 0 reviews.
    </td>
    <td class="rating">                            
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <br>
      Based on 0 reviews.
    </td>
    <td class="rating">                            
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <br>
      Based on 0 reviews.
    </td>
    <td class="rating">                            
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="fa fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x">
        </i>
      </span>
      <br>
      Based on 0 reviews.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Summary
    </td>
    <td class="description">
      More room to move.
      With 80GB or 160GB of storage and up to 40 hours of battery life, the new iPod classic lets you enjoy up to 40,000 songs or up to 200 hours of video or any combi..
    </td>
    <td class="description">
      Video in your pocket.
      Its the small iPod with one very big idea: video. The worlds most popular music player now lets you enjoy movies, TV shows, and more on a two-inch display thats 65% ..
    </td>
    <td class="description">
      Born to be worn.
      Clip on the worlds most wearable music player and take up to 240 songs with you anywhere. Choose from five colors including four new hues to make your musical fashion stateme..
    </td>
    <td class="description">
      Revolutionary multi-touch interface.
      iPod touch features the same multi-touch screen technology as iPhone. Pinch to zoom in on a photo. Scroll through your songs and videos with a flick. Flip thr..
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Weight
    </td>
    <td>1.00kg
    </td>
    <td>5.00kg
    </td>
    <td>5.00kg
    </td>
    <td>5.00kg
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dimensions (L x W x H)
    </td>
    <td>0.00mm x 0.00mm x 0.00mm
    </td>
    <td>0.00mm x 0.00mm x 0.00mm
    </td>
    <td>0.00mm x 0.00mm x 0.00mm
    </td>
    <td>0.00cm x 0.00cm x 0.00cm
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I think, I know reason, but dont know how to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you have got a race condition and you need to find out the reason for it. The exception suggests that after

```
int numOfFields =   availabilityFields.size();
```

the size of availabilityFields is shrinked.

1) This could be a side-effect of something within the loop (although it does not look like anything there would affect availabilityFields). In that case, you should change your for-loop to

```
for(int i=0;i<availabilityFields.size();i++) {
```

to ensure that the size is updated at the beginning of each loop.

2) Another (more probable) reason for the exception could be that another thread reduces the size of your array list while looping. In that case you could synchronize the block or use java.util.Vector (which is synchronized, see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). In any case: use `i<availabilityFields.size()`

Comment: Thanks, it was so easy:) changed to for loop i use now availabilityFields.size(); and its work gr8!:) thanks!:)